# I want to reverse these items in the context

Tags: python, django

I want my items to be displayed in the reverse order in the template
here is my `views.py`

```
@login_required(login_url='/customer/login/')
def myorders(request):
    orders = OrderModel.objects.filter(cid = request.user.id)

    items = {}
    i = 0
    for item in OrderModel.objects.filter(cid = request.user.id):

        items[item.id] = {
            "ordered_items" : item.items,
            "price":item.price,
            "address":AddressModel.objects.filter(userid = request.user.id)[i].address,
            "approval_status":item.approval_status
        }
        i = i + 1;


    context = {'items' : items}
    return render(request,"gupsupapp/myorders.html",context)
```

Comment: Which version of Python are you using? How are you displaying the items in your template at the moment?

Answer (score 0):

Just use `order_by`. 
 Assuming you want to order by `cid`:

```
orders = OrderModel.objects.filter(cid=request.user.id).order_by("-cid")
```

You can use the any field to sort the queryset, just add quotes "" to sort it on ascending order or add a - before to sort it descending "-

Answer (score 0):

If your table having date field then apply order_by on the date field. It will sort the results in reverse order.

```py
result = OrderModel.objects.filter(cid=request.user.id).order_by("-date")
```